# Difference between Virtual Console and Workspace?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

Please explain all differences between Virtual console and Workspace in Linux. If possible also kindly requested to specify definition and/or example. Many thanks.

Comment: Virtual consoles reside on console whereas a workspace resides on X11 display. Also: use search engines before posting a question.